# Validation rails one method for two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phone-number

I have on my form two fields:
phone and mobile phone 
I would like to use one method to validate two fields with one the same method  how to do it??

Answer (score 4):

Any validation can be used for any number of attributes. For example:

```
validates_presence_of :foo, :bar
```

If you're using a custom validation method, just make sure it inspects both attributes - something like this:

```
validate :phone_format

def phone_format
  [phone, mobile].each do |attr|
     errors.add(attr, "some error message") unless attr =~ /some regex/
  end
end
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

Write a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators)